# How to translate regexp_replace from Oracle to Snowflake?

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I'm migrating some queries from Oracle to Snowflake and I got stuck with `regexp_replace(column, '\\W', null)`.

In Oracle it replaces empty strings with null and it removes some characters, i.e. `218.55` becomes `21855`

In Snowflake it replaces every single value with null and I need it to do the same like in Oracle.

What is the equivalent function I can use in Snowflake?

Comment: `regexp_replace(column, '\\W', '')` should work. My guess is that snowflake is literally shoving `NULL` into the string as you would when concatenating strings (`'218' || NULL || '55'`) which results in a fully NULL string for output. Using a blank string `''` makes this work just like Oracle. I would make this an answer, but I would prefer to be able to explain WHY instead of just guessing.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't replace anything at all...

Comment: Interesting. `SELECT regexp_replace('218.55', '\\W', '');` returns `21855`.

Comment: if that's not working for you, can you provide your full query and tell us the context in which you are running it?

Comment: select regexp_replace(column, '\\W', '') from table;
select regexp_replace('100.00', '\\W', '')
Both give 100.00 in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

So JNevill did most the work. But given it very much seems to be a concatenation problem, why not use the replace of empty string to get what seems like broken Oracle behavior (if you floats are all the same decimal places this is a indirect why to covert to fixed point). And then use NULLIF to convert empties to  NULL

```
SELECT '*'||column1||'*' as input,
   '*' || null || '*' as null_test,
   '*'||regexp_replace(column1, '\\W', null)||'*' as reg_null,
   '*'||regexp_replace(column1, '\\W', '')||'*' as reg_empty,
   nullif(regexp_replace(column1, '\\W', ''),'') as nullif
FROM VALUES
  ('218.55'),
  ('');
```

gives:

| INPUT | NULL_TEST | REG_NULL | REG_EMPTY | NULLIF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *218.55* | null | null | *21855* | 21855 |
| ** | null | null | ** | null |

extra stars there so strings could be seen.

Comment: select regexp_replace('100.00', '\\W', '') still gives 100.00 in Snowflake.